# How to express an unusual query using ElasticSearch and/or Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

How to query index given the following scenario.

Docs have the following attributes:

```
body: # text
shares: # array of share(s)
    share:
        orgid: # text
        role: # text
```

Here are a few sample docs:

```
docs = [
    {'body':'hello', 'shares':[{'orgid':'abc.de.1', 'role':'11'}, 
                                       {'orgid':'abc', 'role':'1'}]},
    {'body':'world', 'shares':[{'orgid':'abc.de', 'role':'111'}]},
    {'body':'today', 'shares':[{'orgid':'abc', 'role':'111'}]}
]
```

Using ElasticSearch syntax, I want to do the following queries:

```
Give me all docs where prefix of 'shares.orgid' = 'abc' and prefix of shares.role = '11'
    Should return: all of them
Give me all docs where prefix of 'shares.orgid' = 'abc.de' and prefix of shares.role = '111'
    Should return: world
Give me all docs where prefix of 'shares.orgid' = 'abc.de.1' and prefix of shares.role = '11'
    Should return: nothing
Give me all docs where prefix of 'shares.orgid' = 'abc' and prefix of shares.role = '111'
    Should return: world, today
```

As I am researching this I found the following [info](http://blog.sematext.com/2012/10/01/solr-vs-elasticsearch-part-3-searching/) of interest:

In particular:
**ElasticSearch**

> ElasticSearch lets you use two type of queries – has_children and
>   top_children queries to operate on child documents. The first query
>   accepts a query expressed in ElasticSearch Query DSL as well as the
>   child type and it results in all parent documents that have children
>   matching the given query. The second type of query is run against a
>   set number of children documents and then they are aggregated into
>   parent documents. We are also allowed to choose score calculation for
>   the second query type.

Also of interest: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-child-query.html

More re indexing: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/index_.html
Parents & Children

A child document can be indexed by specifying it’s parent when indexing. For example:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/blogs/blog_tag/1122?parent=1111 -d '{
    "tag" : "something"
}'
```

When indexing a child document, the routing value is automatically set to be the same as it’s parent, unless the routing value is explicitly specified using the routing parameter.

EDIT:

I'm getting closer. Here is a test using a wrapper that I am trying out that demonstrates an approach. I will write a test to demonstrate a solution to the question/problem. https://github.com/aparo/pyes/blob/master/tests/test_nested.py. I ran that test and tweaked it to use PrefixQuery and it works.

Per commenter javanna, child query is not the direction to go. Here is example excerpts using pyes:

```
from pyes.filters import TermFilter, NestedFilter
from pyes.query import FilteredQuery, MatchAllQuery, BoolQuery, TermQuery, PrefixQuery



# from their unit test setup
self.conn.index({"field1": "value1",
                 "nested1": [{"n_field1": "n_value1_1",
                              "n_field2": "n_value2_1"},
                         {"n_field1": "n_value1_2",
                          "n_field2": "n_value2_2"}]},
    self.index_name, self.document_type, 1)
self.conn.index({"field1": "value1",
                 "nested1": [{"n_field1": "n_value1_1",
                              "n_field2": "n_value2_2"},
                         {"n_field1": "n_value1_2",
                          "n_field2": "n_value2_1"}]},
    self.index_name, self.document_type, 2)

self.conn.index({"field1": "value1",
                 "nested1": [{"n_field1": "ni",
                              "n_field2": "11"},
                         {"n_field1": "n_value1_2",
                          "n_field2": "n_value2_1"}]},
    self.index_name, self.document_type, 3)

self.conn.index({"field1": "value1",
                 "nested1": [{"n_field1": "ni.kirmse.104",
                              "n_field2": "111"},
                         {"n_field1": "n_value1_2",
                          "n_field2": "n_value2_1"}]},
    self.index_name, self.document_type, 4)

self.conn.refresh(self.index_name)


# just hacked their test to quickly see if I could do a prefix query on beginning of nested array/list values.

q = FilteredQuery(MatchAllQuery(),
    NestedFilter('nested1',
        BoolQuery(must=[PrefixQuery('nested1.n_field1', 'ni'),
                        PrefixQuery('nested1.n_field2', '111')])))
resultset = self.conn.search(query=q, indices=self.index_name, doc_types=[self.document_type])
```

Comment: How to index your data is really important and depends on your data. We'd need to know something more about it. What does your document represent? Why did you think about a prent-child relation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to do this using pyes, a python elasticsearch wrapper.

I grabbed one of their tests here: https://github.com/aparo/pyes/blob/master/tests/test_nested.py

To answer the question, I modified the test to demonstrate how to achieve the objective.

```
class NestedSearchTestCase(ESTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(NestedSearchTestCase, self).setUp()

        mapping = {
            'shares': {
                'type': 'nested'
            }
        }
        self.conn.create_index(self.index_name)
        self.conn.put_mapping(self.document_type, {'properties': mapping}, self.index_name)
        self.conn.index({"body": "hello",
                         "shares": [{"orgid": "abc.de.1",
                                      "role": "11"},
                                    {"orgid": "abc",
                                      "role": "1"}]},
                        self.index_name, self.document_type, 1)

        self.conn.index({"body": "world",
                         "shares": [{"orgid": "abc.de",
                                      "role": "111"}]},
                        self.index_name, self.document_type, 2)

        self.conn.index({"body": "today",
                         "shares": [{"orgid": "abc",
                                      "role": "111"}]},
                        self.index_name, self.document_type, 3)

        self.conn.refresh(self.index_name)

    def test_nested_filter(self):
        q = FilteredQuery(MatchAllQuery(),
            NestedFilter('shares',
                BoolQuery(must=[PrefixQuery('shares.orgid', 'abc'),
                                PrefixQuery('shares.role', '11')])))
        resultset = self.conn.search(query=q, indices=self.index_name, doc_types=[self.document_type])
        self.assertEquals(resultset.total, 3)
        # prints: hello, world, today
        print ', '.join([r['body'] for r in resultset])


        q = FilteredQuery(MatchAllQuery(),
            NestedFilter('shares',
                BoolQuery(must=[PrefixQuery('shares.orgid', 'abc.de'),
                                PrefixQuery('shares.role', '111')])))
        resultset = self.conn.search(query=q, indices=self.index_name, doc_types=[self.document_type])
        self.assertEquals(resultset.total, 1)
        # prints: world
        print ', '.join([r['body'] for r in resultset])


        q = FilteredQuery(MatchAllQuery(),
            NestedFilter('shares',
                BoolQuery(must=[PrefixQuery('shares.orgid', 'abc.de.1'),
                                PrefixQuery('shares.role', '11')])))
        resultset = self.conn.search(query=q, indices=self.index_name, doc_types=[self.document_type])
        self.assertEquals(resultset.total, 0)
        # prints: nothing
        print ', '.join([r['body'] for r in resultset])


        q = FilteredQuery(MatchAllQuery(),
            NestedFilter('shares',
                BoolQuery(must=[PrefixQuery('shares.orgid', 'abc'),
                                PrefixQuery('shares.role', '111')])))
        resultset = self.conn.search(query=q, indices=self.index_name, doc_types=[self.document_type])
        self.assertEquals(resultset.total, 2)
        # prints: world, today
        print ', '.join([r['body'] for r in resultset])
```